# concept of retain in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am new in objective c.....i am aware of alloc and release.....
but dont know when and why to use retain statement......
please help....need just basic idea...

please also tell something about copy statement.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`retain` is the opposite of `release`, instead of decreasing the reference counter it increases it by one. When you remove an object from an NSArray you usually have to `retain` as removing it will cause `release` to be called on that object. retain is used when you store a reference to an object as an instance variable in one of your classes. If you are using properties most `retain` calls will be done automatically for you.

What is important for correct memory management is that for each `retain` there needs to be a `release` or you will create a memory leak.

```
@property (retain) NSNumber* input;
```

Would generate:

```
- (void) setInput: (NSNumber*)input
{
    [input autorelease];
    input= [input retain];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should read this : http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 3):

The concept of `retain` is the exact meaning of the English word; you want the object to stick around.

By conventions almost all objects you get access to, be it return values or your method argument, are *autoreleased*. Which means that they will be *"garbage collected"* sometime later, where *"sometime later"* is shortly after the current method exits.

So if you want to have the object sticking around even after the current method exits, then you need to `retain` the object. All objects you ever get access to are *autoreleased* and will go away, unless you explicitly call `retain`, or got them from a method containing any of these words:

- `alloc`
- `copy`
- `new`

These three words in a method name implies a `retain`. Example of two retained objects:

```
Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
Foo* bar = [foo copy];
```

Example of who objects that are not retained:

```
Foo* foo = [Foo fooWithInt:42];
Bar* bar = foo.bar;
```

`release` is the opposite, is means; *"I no longer need the object and it can be discared immediately"*.

`autorlease` is a bit more lenient and means; *"I no longer need the object, but keep it around for a while in case anyone wants to retain it"*. You should **always** autorelease all return values from your own methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this Objective-C introductory article for Java programmers](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377302&seqNum=2)  which does a good job at explaining this.